# Galaxy Nexus Ignores viewport meta tag

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap app. My app is designed as a 320px interface. My viewport tag within the app is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no"/>
```

This works as expected on my Galaxy S2 running Ice Cream Sandwich. The 320px interface fills the entire width of the screen.

However, when testing the above code on a Galaxy Nexus, the viewport is 360px wide. So my elements do not fill the screen. I have tried adding the following line to my Cordova's appname.java file:

```
this.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

However, this has no effect.

Comment: In your viewport, content="width=320" please change this to width=device-width

Answer (score 13):

Try replacing it with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

It should resize to the specific device, however I can't test this.

Comment: I second what Wayneio said - I've used this throughout a PhoneGap app which is now on Google Play and it resizes for every device. Also, to answer the last question in the bounty; no, you only need one CSS file.

Comment: I too have been using this in my phonegap/cordova based apps and have over 50 published. I use a slightly different approach though as I add `user-scalable=no` to the viewport meta as well. This really should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 5):

The answers I see are super close but they're ignoring one point he brought up: his interface is designed for 320px. width=device-width will make it fit to screen, but that doesn't ensure his interface will stay at 320px.

My solution is just building a little bit on Wayneio's answer, providing the necessary CSS / markup to ensure you need only one stylesheet (and that it doesn't need to be a responsive one).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="interfaceWrap">
        // insert interface here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What this markup does is allows you to confine your interface to a specific container that you can set properties to via CSS. What I would recommend is something like this:

```
#interfaceWrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This basically tells the browser that no matter meta-tag viewport sets the page width to, place my interface in the horizontal center (`margin-left & margin-right: auto`) and keep it fixed to 320px width (`width: 320px`). You can add any combination of styles to get what you're truly looking for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: upvote for explaining everything so clearly. I think this would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Check this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/15006907) for customizing meta tag

Comment: That is a nice and quite handy presentation you linked. Thank you.